# I can't scrap salary text using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want someone to help me figure this out I want to scrap text value of salary (Confidential) using beautiful soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
result=requests.get("https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/WBHqaf7WeZYe-Senior-Python-Developer-Trufla-Cairo-Egypt?o=1&l=sp&t=sj&a=python|search-v3")
src=result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src,"lxml")
```

after this I used

```
salary=soup.find_all("span":{"class":"css-4xky9y"})
```

but it returns empty list

ـــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــ

```
import requestsfrom bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result=requests.get("https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/WBHqaf7WeZYe-Senior-Python-Developer-Trufla-Cairo-Egypt?o=1&l=sp&t=sj&a=python|search-v3")src=result.contentsoup = BeautifulSoup(src,"lxml")salary=soup.find("div",{'id':'app'})salary_text=salary.contents[0]h=salary_text.contents[4]

print(h)
```

when I print (h) it gives me the value

Please help me Guys finding the text value of salary

I have tried in past 5 days using what is mentioned in above.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a complete code example. What do you mean "I tried to go inside until i find Salary value Confidential"? Please be sure to show the code that does this. Then show what result you get and explain what you want instead.

Comment: if you run this code `with open("test.html","w") as fh:
    fh.write(str(src))` , you will notice that `request` is not getting the page content, you might have to move to selenium type of framework.

Answer (score 0):

If the salary information is in a `<span>` tag, you can use a code snippet like,

```
salary = soup.find("span", {"class": "salary"}).text
```

If this doesn't work, or you are unable to find the specific tag & class, you can always use the `find_all()` method search for `<span>` tags, then filter through the resulting list to find the tag that contains the salary information.

```
for span in soup.find_all("span"):

    if span is not None and \ 
        span.text is not None and \
            "salary" in span.text:
                salary = span.text
                break
    else:
        salary = None # or np.nan
```